# missing extracting text with beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup to extract data from ul and li tags. I can get a date, but some words are missing and there is no place between the line.

```
<li>Developing <span class="bte bte-78432-940">&nbsp;</span>pricing strategy that maximizes profits <span class="bte bte-78432-947">&nbsp;</span>market share <span class="bte bte-78432-962">&nbsp;</span>considers customer satisfaction</li>
<li>Supporting <span class="bte bte-78432-1041">&nbsp;</span>and <span class="bte bte-78432-1045">&nbsp;</span>launching</li>
```

HTML view text:
- Developing a pricing strategy that maximizes profits and market share but considers customer satisfaction
- Supporting sale and service launching

I receive the below text:
Developing a pricing strategy that maximizes profits  market share  considers customer satisfactionSupporting  and  launching

There are missing the words, for example, a, and, sale and service. In addition, they are written in one line and continuously.

How can I get the exact text as in HTML view, if no bulttet, it should at least contain underline between each bullet.

Piece of code:

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    ul_jobdetail = soup.find_all('ul',{'class':'job-detail-req'})
    i=1
    for ul_jdetail in ul_jobdetail:
        if i==1:
            duties = ul_jdetail.getText()
            print(ul_jdetail.text)
        else:
            requirements=ul_jdetail.getText()
        i=i+1
```

Comment: The HTML text is extracted from this website: https://www.bongthom.com/job_detail/various_positions_78432.html

Answer (score 2):

The page seems coded through CSS, so first load that CSS, parse it for required info (missing words) and put those words in the soup:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.bongthom.com/job_detail/various_positions_78432.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')
css_url = soup.select_one('link[data-src="escape"]')['href']

for css_class, word in re.findall(r'\.(bte-\d+-\d+).*?"(.*?)"', requests.get(css_url).text):
    for span in soup.select('span.{}'.format(css_class)):
        span.string = word + ' '
        span.unwrap()

for li in soup.select('.job-detail-req li'):
    print(li.text)
```

Prints:

```
Developing a pricing strategy that maximizes profits and market share but considers customer satisfaction
Supporting sale and service launching
Creating promotion, advertising and event planning
Developing and managing advertising campaigns
Organizing company conference, Trade shows, and major events
Building brand awareness
Evaluating and maintaining marketing strategy
Directing, planning and coordinating marketing plan
Researching market demand
Handling social media, public relation efforts, and marketing content
Build strategic relationships and partner with key industry players, and agencies
Be in charge of marketing budget and allocate
Up-to-date with the latest trends and best practices in online marketing and measurement
Identify weaknesses in existing marketing campaigns and develop pragmatic solution within budgetary constraints
Communicate with senior management about marketing initiatives and brainstorm fresh strategies
Bachelor degree in Marketing, Business Administration, Communication or relate field (MBA Preferred)
At least five years’ experience in Marketing and Promotion

...etc.
```

Comment: For future reference - how did you know that the missing words were located in this particular stylesheet - `css_url = soup.select_one('link[data-src="escape"]')['href']`?

Comment: @JackFleeting I looked at Firefox developer tools (clicked on `::before` CSS selector of one encoded `<span>` tag and Firefox showed me the filename where is the CSS rule.

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but I can't see in Firefox developer any reference to `https://www.bongthom.com/css/style_78432_141.css`; where is it hiding?

Comment: @JackFleeting The page changes the CSS on every reload. You need to extract it by the `link[data-src="escape"]` selector.

Comment: Very sneaky on their part!